# What are the values of $a$ that satisfy the equation $\frac{ax^2+ax-1}{2(x+\frac{5}{4})^2+\frac{47}{8}} < 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discriminant

I got this question in a test today, I was stumped on how to do it. I am right to say that since $2(x+\frac{5}{4})^2+\frac{47}{8}$ is always positive $ax^2+ax-1$ is always negative. So, $$ax^2+ax-1<0$$$$Discriminant < 0$$$$(a)^2-4(a)(-1)<0$$$$a(a+4)<0$$$$-4<a<0$$ or is it $$ax^2+ax-1<2x^2+5x+9$$$$(a-2)x^2+(a-5)x-10<0$$$$Discriminant < 0$$$$(a-5)^2-4(a-2)(-10)<0$$

Comment: Should it be $-4<a<0$?

Comment: @CYKwong edited sorry for the mistake

Comment: as @DeepSea pointed it should be also $a<0$, but in this particular problem it doesn't affect the final answer. So, your answer is fine, though you forgot about $a<0$.

Comment: @NegligibleSenescence whats the difference between the first one and the second one? Cause I cant spot the error in the second one

Comment: @engineeriscool How did you get $ax^2+ax-1<2x^2+5x+9$? Since, $f(x)$ is strictly positive you are not interested in $f(x)$ anymore, so it only lasts to think about the sign of $ax^2 + ax - 1$.

Comment: $\frac{ax^2+ax-1}{2(x+\frac{5}{4})^2+\frac{47}{8}} < 0$ to $ax^2+ax-1 < 2(x+\frac{5}{4})^2+\frac{47}{8}$ @NegligibleSenescence

Comment: @engineeriscool It seems like you're multiplying $0 \cdot( 2(x+\frac{5}{4})^2+\frac{47}{8})$, doesn't it? It should be equal to $0$ on RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: You want $a < 0$, and $a^2 - 4a(-1) < 0$